# Replacing certain parts of text file with variables in batch

Tags: batch, batch-file

I'm trying to replace `stat.score` and `stat.level` with corresponding variables, but it just prints stat.score=000099 to every line.

Here's the code:

```sh
@echo off
mode con cols=100 lines=40
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
:GameRender
del %cd%\assets\GameRender\pets\cthulhu\GameRender.txt
set "stat.score=000099"
set "stat.level=0"
set "Render_Ln=0"

for /L %%a in (1,1,39) do (

if !Render_Ln! EQU 39 goto :pause
set /a "Render_Ln=!Render_Ln!+1"

for /f "usebackq delims=@ skip=1" %%g in ("%cd%\assets\GameRender\pets\cthulhu\GameRender_source.txt") do set Line=%%g
echo:!Line! | findstr "stat."
    if %errorlevel% EQU 0 (
        set Line=%Line:stat.score=!stat.score!%
    )
echo:!Line!>>"%cd%\assets\GameRender\pets\cthulhu\GameRender.txt"
)
:pause
pause
for %%a in (%cd%\assets\GameRender\pets\cthulhu\GameRender.txt) do type %%a 
pause>nul
```

And here is [GameRender_source.txt.](http://pastebin.com/A9jfwnva)

Comment: [Debugging your batch files](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_debugging.php)

Comment: Just looking at your formatting, without testing your code... I noticed that you are using a piping method for "do set ... | ...". Try this instead; do (newline ... ... ... newline) instead. It might help? Also try printing to screen Line to see if you are grabbing what you think you are.

Comment: Apply _Delayed Expansion_ consistently e.g. in `if %errorlevel% EQU 0 (`. Moreover, think about `set Line=%Line:stat.score=!stat.score!%` command (I'd try `call set "Line=%%Line:stat.score=!stat.score!%%"` or `call :someproc` where the `:someproc` subroutine might be something like `set "Line=!Line:stat.score=%stat.score%!"&exit /b`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey so I was able to solve this with your assistance by changing the GameRender_source.txt content to be only on 1 line.

```
for /f "usebackq delims=@" %%a in ("%cd%\assets\GameRender\pets\cthulhu\GameRender_source.txt") do set Render=%%a
call set "Render=%%Render:stat.score=!stat.score!%%"
call set "Render=%%Render:stat.level=!stat.level!%%"
echo:!Render!>>"%cd%\assets\GameRender\pets\cthulhu\GameRender.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use a PowerShell script to replace the values; the script should be somewhat self-explanatory:

```sh
(Get-Content d:\GameRender.txt) | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace "stat.score", "000099" -replace "stat.level", "0"} | Set
-Content d:\GameRender.txt
```